# MySQL - using LIKE operator with UNHEX() function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use MySQL function UNHEX() with operator LIKE but i can't get the expected result as `$result_2_expected`.

What i'm doing wrong?
I'm trying the ways bellow, all without success:

- LIKE UNHEX('%4272756365%')
- LIKE '%UNHEX('4272756365')%'
- LIKE '%UNHEX(4272756365)%'

**Experience with Equal operator (Success):**

```
$name_1 = bin2hex("Bruce Wayne"); //4272756365205761796e65
$query_1 = "SELECT `NAME` FROM `USERS_TABLE` WHERE `NAME` = UNHEX('{$name_1}')"; // UNHEX('4272756365205761796e65')


$result_1 = [0][NAME] => "Bruce Wayne"; // Success
```

**Experience with LIKE operator (Fail):**

```
$name_2 = bin2hex("Bruce"); // 4272756365
$query_2 = "SELECT `NAME` FROM `USERS_TABLE` WHERE `NAME` LIKE UNHEX('%{$name_2}%')"; // UNHEX('%4272756365%')

$result_2 = [] => null; // Fail

$result_2_expected = [0][NAME] => "Bruce Wayne"; [1][NAME] => "Bruce Willis"; [2][NAME] => "Bruce Springsteen"; // Expected as Success
```

Comment: Replace percent signs with their HEX representation.

Comment: Works Well. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have put the wildcard characters into the call to `UNHEX` instead of concatenating them outside it, and that is making `UNHEX` return `NULL`, which will always cause `LIKE` to return `false`.

Change

```
LIKE UNHEX('%{$name_2}%')
```

to

```
LIKE  CONCAT('%', UNHEX('{$name_2}'), '%')
```

and your code will work as expected. Alternatively, you could do as @Akina suggested in the comments, and replace the `%` signs in the call to `UNHEX` with their hex representation (`25`) and replace your code with

```
LIKE UNHEX('25{$name_2}25')
```

Comment: Works with both solutions. Thank you